# Is it bad practice to use globals in php to determine page layout?

Tags: php, html

I'm quite new to php, I'm currently attempting to use it to determine what content should be loaded. It's working perfectly but I'm just wondering if there are any downsides I may run into or is what I'm doing considered bad practice? Because it feels very wrong.

This is what I'm doing:

```
<body>
    <?php
        $req = "templates" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "_layout.php";
        if (file_exists($req)) {
            include("templates" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "_layout.php");
        }
        else {
            include("templates/errors/404.php");
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

I have a templates folder, in which there are a bunch of different files like home_template.php, about_template.php etc., This way when someone navigates to website.com/home - the home_template.php will be loaded into the body section. (The landing page is "_layout.php", so it will load on the index page.)

Comment: Is it.. tends to be opinion-based - which is off-topic here. But it may be worth studying the MVC architecture and draw notes from that (as it deals with a similar idea)

Comment: Douglas Crockford's opinion: "Global variables are evil in all languages." https://frontendmasters.com/courses/javascript-the-good-parts/avoiding-confusing-code-b/